# How to Calculate the runtime memory usage of a C program in windows

Tags: c

Need to Calculate the run-time memory usage for a C program running in Windows. Basically the memory usage that includes data and stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx). Pass `GetCurrentProcess` as process to get information about current process.